# Error when calling MR_createEntity on a NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

When i simply call MR_createEntity, i get an exc_bad_access error. As i'm new to magicalRecord, I can't find where the bug is coming from.

**The code :**

*TMTAppDelegate.m*

```
//TMTAppDelegate.m
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack];



    NSArray *trajetsRawArray = @[@{@"km" : @125, @"mn":@110, @"adressStart" : @"Metz", @"adressEnd" : @"Gérardmer", },
                                 @{@"km" : @4, @"mn":@14, @"adressStart" : @"Plappeville", @"adressEnd" : @"Metz"},
                                 @{@"km" : @312, @"mn":@200, @"adressStart" : @"Metz", @"adressEnd" : @"Paris"},
                                 @{@"km" : @413, @"mn":@236, @"adressStart" : @"Marseille", @"adressEnd" : @"Toulouse"},
                                 @{@"km" : @2, @"mn":@4, @"adressStart" : @"Ban-St-Martin", @"adressEnd" : @"Metz"},
                                 @{@"km" : @65, @"mn":@63, @"adressStart" : @"Metz", @"adressEnd" : @"Gérardmer"}
                                 ];

    //[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton"]];
    self.trajetsManager = [[TMTTrajetsManager alloc]initWithArray:trajetsRawArray];
    NSLog(@"hello");
    return YES;
}
```

*TMTTrajetsManager.m*

```
//  TMTTrajetsManager.m
-(id)initWithArray:(NSArray *)array {

    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        for (NSDictionary *trajetDico in array){

            Trajet *trajet = [Trajet MR_createEntity];
            trajet.distance = [trajetDico objectForKey:@"km"];
            trajet.duration = [trajetDico objectForKey:@"mn"];
            trajet.start_point = [trajetDico objectForKey:@"adressStart"];
            trajet.end_point = [trajetDico objectForKey:@"adressEnd"];
            self.autoManager = [[TMTTrajetAutoManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
        }
    }

    return self;
}
```

The error :

[image]

Comment: What you are seeing is a stack overflow, because `+entityName` somehow calls `+MR_entityName` again. Did you implement `+entityName` in your `Trajet` class? If so, can you show the code?

Comment: No i didn't implemented it. The Trajet class is the automatically generated class from my core data model

Comment: what version of MagicalRecord are you using? It could be a bug, make sure that you are using the latest version, for example MagicalRecord v2.3.0. Please notice: you are creating TMTTrajetAutoManager array.count - times...

Comment: I changed the TMTTrajetAutoManager. This was a mistake. I didn't find the magical record version number but i'm using the library from the develop branche and i'm up to date

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Disable MR_SHORTHAND, and use the method names with the MR_ prefix explicitly. It looks like the this method is recognizing that this method exists via the shorthand support. Shorthand support is now deprecated and will be [removed in the next version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985859/mr-shorthand-does-not-work) of MagicalRecord.

Comment: You can disable shorthand by removing the #define MR_SHORTHAND line in your .pch file.